# Rspec error - relationship between current user and another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am testing my employees_controller, and in my index test for signed-in users, I am getting an error that seems to be related to my model relationships.

The test is:

```
describe "for signed-in user" do
  before(:each) do
    @user = test_sign_in(Factory(:user))
  end

  it "should have the right title" do
    get :index
    response.should have_selector('title', :content => "Employee List")
  end
```

I have render_views set.  I also have each user tied to a location, and the employee index view is supposed to show employees for the user's location.  And in my index view, I have the following code to show the name of the location of the employees:

```
<h1>Listing employees for <%= current_user.location.name %> </h1>
```

When I run my test, I get an error message that contains 
    "ActionView::Template::Error:
    undefined method 'name for nil:NilClass"

In my factories.rb file, I did set the user's location id to a valid id.  Why is current_user.location returning nil?  What am I missing in the test?  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Most probably, it's just that the login process in not correct. This is how i do it. I have a /spec/support/controller_macros.rb and inside :

```
module ControllerMacros
  def login_user
    before(:each) do
      @request.env["devise.mapping"] = :user
      @user = Factory(:user)
      sign_in @user
    end
  end
end
```

Now, in my controller specs :

```
describe AbilitiesController do
    login_user

  describe "POST 'train' ..." do
    ...
  end
...
```

Comment: I did have a login macro in a spec helper file.  In your login_user macro, what does     @request.env["devise.mapping"] = :user  do?

Comment: i don't really know what it does(nor i care really), but it's how the official devise wiki uses it.